# Using additional Raspberry Pi wifi connections

Tags: pi-zero-w

Successfully I connected my Pi with my wireless connection and it's working properly. But if I need to go outside like a college or my friend's home. Then how will I connect the Pi?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to additional WiFi networks then just add another `network {..}` block to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. Usually you can copy the network block you are using for your home network and just modify **ssid=** and **psk=** needed for the new network.